# r Putting a legend at the bottom of four plots

Tags: r, data-visualization

Currently I have these 4 plots:

```
qqnorm(Adrt,
   main="QQplot for Admiral (Normal)",
   cex.main=2,
   cex.lab=1.5)
qqline(Adrt, col="blue", lwd=1)

qqplot(as.numeric(Adrt), rstd(260, mean = Adrt_Tmu, sd = Adrt_Tsd, nu = Adrt_Tnu),
   main="QQplot for Admiral (Student-t)",
   xlab = "Theoretical Quantiles",
   ylab = "Sample Quantiles",
   cex.main=2,
   cex.lab=1.5)
qqline(as.numeric(Adrt),
   distribution = function(p) qstd(p, mean = Adrt_Tmu, sd = Adrt_Tsd, nu = Adrt_Tnu),
   col="red", lwd=1)

qqplot(as.numeric(Adrt), rsstd(260, mean = Adrt_skewTmu, sd = Adrt_skewTsd, nu = Adrt_skewTnu, xi = Adrt_skewTxi),
   main="QQplot for Admiral (Skewed-t)",
   xlab = "Theoretical Quantiles",
   ylab = "Sample Quantiles",
   cex.main=2,
   cex.lab=1.5)
qqline(as.numeric(Adrt),
   distribution = function(p) qsstd(p, mean = Adrt_skewTmu, sd = Adrt_skewTsd, nu = Adrt_skewTnu, xi = Adrt_skewTxi),
   col="green", lwd=1)

qqplot(as.numeric(Adrt), rsnorm(260, mean = Adrt_skewNmu, sd = Adrt_skewNsd, xi = Adrt_skewNxi),
   main="QQplot for Admiral (Skewed-Normal)",
   xlab = "Theoretical Quantiles",
   ylab = "Sample Quantiles",
   cex.main=2,
   cex.lab=1.5)
qqline(as.numeric(Adrt),
   distribution = function(p) qsnorm(p, mean = Adrt_skewNmu, sd = Adrt_skewNsd, xi = Adrt_skewNxi),
   col="orange", lwd=1)
```

I want to put a legend of the  qqlines at the bottom of the graph so it is not inside them.
I also need them to be spread out throughout the bottom. So instead of 4 rows 1 column, 1 row and 4 columns.

Thanks!

Comment: I've tried to use the layout function but have very little experience with it. Would appreciate any help! Thanks in advance.